# Sliding window segmentation with overlapping for dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

I was working a [research paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323935725_Analyzing_User_Emotions_via_Physiology_Signals) & i found that there is a window sliding segmentation with overlapping windows

[image]

my dataframe is as follows ,

```
    Time  Temperature  BPM  GSR
0    0.5         31.0   70  223
1    1.0         32.0   69  225
2    1.5         31.5   68  230
3    2.0         32.5   67  240
4    2.5         33.0   68  244
5    3.0         34.0   69  250
6    3.5         33.5   68  251
7    4.0         30.0   69  255
8    4.5         30.6   70  252
9    5.0         31.5   71  260
10   5.5         31.0   72  240
11   6.0         32.0   71  250
12   6.5         33.0   70  260
```

Here is the code:

```
from itertools import islice

def window(seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result
```

**But the problem is the above function provides window sliding for 1d list and does not have any overlapping feature**

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aXUH.png) is my expected output.

Comment: Can you provide your expected results for better understanding?

Comment: @shaikmoeed i have added the expected output can , Kindly check! .